# How i can do more beautification of display screen where label and values are there

Tags: forms, gui-design, lean-ux

Hello i need some help to beautification of example for below screenshot. I try searching in but not getting good example.

Any help ? how to make more beautify and standardised

I have design this layout like shown below screenshot. Its very basic UI component. I need to more standardisation as per UX and good UI component.

In simple word i have to do better UX and UI of below screen. Any recommendation ?

[image: Screen example]

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to go about this. But generally, the current table data entries have no form of hierarchy whatsoever.

So we start by:

**1. Creating a hierarchy between the labels and the content:** Here I am doing that by font size and weight. The contrast could be created in a lot of other ways though.

[image]

**2. We then look at the information themselves and check how we can highlight certain data attributes.** *My assumption here is that loan type is a categorical data.* So I'm going to be converting the loan type to tags. Tags are used for items that need to be labeled, categorized, or organized using keywords that describe them.

[image]

3. **The third (and perhaps final ) thing I would do is to look at the table in the context of other elements.** So here I am adding some elevation to the table itself and adding a title just to distinguish it from any other table (or components) that may exist on the same page with it.

[image]